# jQuery unbind after jquery .hide()?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display an icon after it's been hidden using jQuery and another div slides in.
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CU8cv/). basically all I want to do is re display the initial icon after  the user clicks off the search box and the input box slides back to the original width. 
I've tried this:

```
    $('#display_search_two').hide();
    $(".search_icon").click(function() {
    $(".search_icon").hide(300);
    $("#display_search_two").slideDown(1000); 
    $(this).off().hide().show(".search_icon");
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I have also looked into the unbind option,but can't get that to work either. 
Kind regards 
Chris

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/2bHQ3/

Comment: I didn't know about the focusout function thank you but I am still in the same problem if the user doesn't actually click on the input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/CU8cv/1/

```
/* lookup the original width */
var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
$(this).animate({ width: w, left: 92 }, 'slow');

$("#display_search_two").slideUp();
$(".search_icon").show(300);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: that works for every case apart from if the user doesn't actually click on the input. just clicks the icon then click on another page element...
Thank you anyway :D